# how to kill flink ApplicationMaster when jobs failed

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

How make flink application on yarn killed or failed
itself when flink's inner jobs failed? The application is still running no matter how many jobs failed, as a result, the problems can't be found immediately.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can always kill it as any other regular yarn application:

```
yarn application -kill <applicationId>
```

More e.g. here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html

Comment: Is there any way to make application failed itself, so that we can get the failure notification immediately. I have changed flink-conf.yaml many times, while it can't work.

Comment: How do you start your job? Via `yarn-session` or as a cluster per job? If the latter than the cluster should be closed automatically as long as the failure did not happen during submission.

Comment: via yarn-session, the job is submitted to ResourceManager by CliFrontend

Comment: Then yarn-session (flink-cluster running in yarn) is completely separate to inner jobs and therfore should not fail on job-failure.

Comment: okay, maybe I should develop another client application to monitor the job running status. Thank you.